# C# string.split is splitting letter by letter when pulled from IBM Emulator

Tags: c#, split, delimiter

I work in an IBM emulator environment. I'm trying to grab a row of text and split by spaces to return each word in the row. However, when printed to the console it's showing only first letters. This code has worked in the past when utilized on raw text or api results. The same code when implemented on an IBM Emulator does not however.

For example if the row from the emulator is `HEALTHSELECT OF TEXAS`        , the code below would do the first and second console print correctly. With the double for-loop printing only the first letters. The real listed console output is below:

```
looking for healthselect of texas          in away from home care

healthselect
of
texas

looking for h in a 
looking for h in w
looking for h in a
looking for h in y
looking for e in a 
looking for e in w
looking for e in a
looking for e in y
looking for a in a 
looking for a in w
looking for a in a
looking for a in y
```

C# code:

```
public bool inStringAll(string needle, string haystack)
{
    needle = Regex.Replace(needle.ToLower(), @"\r\n", string.Empty);
    haystack = Regex.Replace(haystack.ToLower(), @"\r\n", string.Empty);

    Console.WriteLine($"looking for {needle} in {haystack}");

    string[] needleArr = needle.Split(' ');
    string[] haystackArr = haystack.Split(' ');

    for(int j = 0; j < needleArr.Length; j++)
        Console.WriteLine(needleArr[j]);

    int percent = 0;
    int increment;
    bool decision = false;

    if (needleArr.Length > 3)
         increment = 100 / 3;
    else increment = 100 / needleArr.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < haystackArr.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("looking for " + needle[i] + " in " + haystack[j]);
            if (needleArr[i] == haystackArr[j])
            {
                percent += increment;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Percent: {percent}%");

    if (percent >= 50)
        decision = true;

    return decision;
}
```

Has anyone worked with an emulator of this kind and had any issues getting these values correctly? I've worked with old attachmate systems using EXTRA! Basic and there was no issues, but this is my first client with IBM systems using C#.net so it may be different.

Comment: Should you be printing from the arrays not the strings?

Comment: @SBFrancies is right, in `Console.WriteLine("looking for " + needle[i] + " in " + haystack[j]);` you're printing from the string not the array. If you use an indexer on a string it'll return that character of the string.

Comment: @SBFrancies OMG its always a little oversight like that haha, thank you both! how do i mark a comment as the answer? or can i do that?